# ErrorException thrown with message "Trying to get property 'subo_name' of non-object

Tags: laravel

ErrorException thrown with message

> "Trying to get property 'subo_name' of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\org\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)"

**Main** model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Maino extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'maino_name'
    ];


     public function subo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subo');
    }
}
```

**Sub** model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subo extends Model
{   

    protected $fillable = [
        'subo_name','maino_id'
    ];

    public function maino()
    {   

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Maino');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

}
```

**user** model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','role_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];



     public function role()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
     }


     public function profile()
     {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Profileinfo');
     }

     public function suborg()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subo');
     }
}
```

**UserController** code

```
public function index()
{  
  // $user=User::all();
     $users=User::all();
     return view('users.index',compact('users'));
}
```

index.blade.php

```
    @extends('mainorg.main')
    @section('title','Users')
    @section('content')
    <!-- DataTables Example -->
            @if(Session::has('status'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    {{ Session::get('status') }}
                </div>
      @endif
            <div class="card mb-3">

              <div class="card-header">
                <!-- <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
               MainOrg  --><div class="container"><a href="{{URL::asset('users/create')}}"><button class="btn btn-primary float-right">Add SubOrg</button></a></div></div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>user</th>
                        <th>main org</th>
                        <th>suborg</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                      <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>user</th>
                        <th>main org</th>
                        <th>suborg</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                      </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->role->role_name}}</td>

                        <td>{{$user->suborg->subo_name}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{{ route('users.edit',$user->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><form action="{{route('users.destroy',$user->id)}}" method="post">
            @method('DELETE')
            @csrf
            <input type="submit" name="" value="DELETE" class="btn btn-danger">
          </form></td>

                      </tr>
                      @endforeach

                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endsection
```

I am facing problem regarding to this code so please help me solve this problem ......................

Answer (score 1):

The error means that one of your `$users` doesn't have a `suborg` while looping. So `{{ $user->suborg }}` is `null`, and you can't access `->name` of `null`. To handle this, restrict your users to only those that have a `suborg`, or check while looping:

```
public function index() {  
  $users=User::with('suborg')->has('suborg')->get();
  return view('users.index',compact('users'));
}
```

Note: You can use both `with` and `has` in a single query; they do different things.

Or, while looping your users, check existence:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
  <td>
  @if($user->suborg)
  {{ $user->suborg->subo_name }}
  @else
  No Suborg
  @endif
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: sir, but both have sub ids

Comment: And you have database records in your `subo` table with `ids` of `1` and `2`? There are plenty of cases where your `id` can be set, but the relationship doesn't exist. Records are deleted, ids mismatch, etc. Don't rely on it, and use the methods above to constrain records or check for existence.

Answer (score 0):

When you creating relation between two or more models then you should use relational method during model use using `with` in your eloquent call, you can also write when you want to pass multiple like - `with(['suborg', 'example'])`. In index method, bellow `$users` variable make `dd($users)` and check is there have any relational data. If found I think, it should work.

```
public function index()
{  
  // $user=User::all();
     $users=User::with('suborg')->get();
     return view('users.index',compact('users'));
 }
```

And your index.blade.php

```
@foreach($users as $user)
     <tr>
         <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->role->role_name}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->suborg->subo_name || 'Not Found'}}</td>
         ......
@endforeach
```

Comment: Trying to get property 'subo_name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\org\resources\views\users\index.blade.php) this problem facing now

Comment: Bellow `$users=User::with('suborg')->get();` did you `dd($users)` ?

Comment: array:2 [▼
  0 => array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Siddhesh Aldar"
    "role_id" => 2
    "subo_id" => 1
    "email" => "itsmealdar@gmail.com"
    "email_verified_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2019-07-31 13:47:48"
    "updated_at" => "2019-07-31 13:47:48"
    "suborg" => null
  ]
  1 => array:9 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "suresh aldar"
    "role_id" => 1
    "subo_id" => 2
    "email" => "admin@gmail.com"
    "email_verified_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2019-07-31 14:30:02"
    "updated_at" => "2019-07-31 14:30:02"
    "suborg" => null
  ]
]

Comment: Your relation clearly showing that suborg is null. That's mean you have no data in suborg thats why you are getting this error. If you want to keep null and don't show any error then do ` {{ $user->suborg->subo_name || 'Not Found'}}` this will show blank if suborg has no value.